# how to make FPS camera in 2d game unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, frame-rate

I make a game with unity in 2d mode.
I want FPS mode and a camera such as DOOM game that hand are in from of player view but in 2d game mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make camere child of Player object so it moves and rotates along with player.
But you stil probably want it to be perspective camera and " 3D" game even if you use flat objects with no depth.
Doom was 2D but it was pretending to be 3D

It all depends what you mean by 2D, there are many ways depending on what you want.